# Top margin UITableViewController after popViewController action

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, viewcontroller

I have simple ViewController with UITableView. 
In first time (viewDidLoad) table load good (without top margin). In didSelectRowAtIndexPath I push new View Controller in navigationController stack and after back action i have top margin in UITableView. 
It happens only in first time !!!
If i use

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        mainTable.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

it fixed but i see animation and it not good !
In viewWillAppear it's not work at all

Thanks....

Comment: No. It is simple UITableView with detail options view controller. In ViewController i have only UITableView and navigation bar

Comment: Thanks. Can not find this option in Xcode 6.3.1

Answer (score 1):

> Thanks. Can not find this option in Xcode 6.3.1 –  Sergey Burd 56 mins ago

[image]